# Uncertainty principle for incompatible observables whose probability distributions lack well-defined moments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, probability, statistics

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle states that the product of standard deviations (or variances) for incompatible observables has a non-zero lower bound (with a zero lower bound reserved for compatible ones). However, not all probability distributions have well-defined moments, such as mean and variance. For example, the celebrated Cauchy-Lorentz (or Lorentzian) distribution has undefined moments (i.e., the moment values could be $\infty-\infty$, $\infty/\infty$, or etc.), meaning their values *fluctuate chaotically around unpredictable points*. In such scenarios, can one establish the existence of a Heisenberg-type inequality or equality in general? If so, how is it defined?

How about for probability distributions whose moments, such as mean and variance, are defined, but infinite ($\infty$)?

In the special case of the Lorentzian distribution, it's indeed possible to establish a Heisenberg-type equality for the product of its Half Width at Half Maximum (HWHM) and the Half Width at 1/e Maximum (HW1/eM) of its Fourier transformed distribution, known as the Laplace distribution. The product is always a constant. This explains why we encounter a Heisenberg-type relation between the HWHM of a Lorentzian-broadened quantum energy level (natural broadening), denoted as $\Delta E$, and its lifetime, denoted as $Δt$, (as expressed by $ΔEΔt = ħ/2$). It's worth noting that $ΔE$ no longer represents the standard deviation in this context.

I would appreciate hearing your insights on this matter.